# Markdown emphasis - re substitution

Tags: python, regex, parsing, markdown

How would you implement Markddown's `emphasis` or `bold` with regular expressions?

Or how is it possible to substitute re `\*\*(.*)\*\*` with what is inside `** **`?

Comment: Implement? Regex's are simply patterns. What you do with the pattern is up to you and your language of choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.sub()`:

```
import re

myRegex = re.compile(r"\*\*(.+?)\*\*")
string = "some **text** and some **more**"

output = myRegex.sub(r"\1", string)
```

Comment: -1: This only works if there's a single block in the string (i.e., ``string = "some **text** plus **other text**`` fails). You should use the regular expression to do the replacement: ``output = myRegex.sub('\\1', string)``

Comment: Good point. I would have just looped the search until there were no more results, but your way is much more elegent. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: what is the meaning of `r"\1"`?

Comment: @Halst: `\n` where n is a digit, refers to the nth group of the regex.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Fantasizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797516/markdown-emphasis-re-substitution/5797704#5797704) has the right idea.

Additionally, you should take a look at the Python based [Markdown Library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown)

Specifically look through `inlinepatterns.py` to see how they match 'strong' (bold) and 'emphasis'